# Javascript slideshow only shows first image, buttons don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So off the bat I will admit that I only know the basics of JS. I have done a few courses online and am now looking at code for things I want to do so I can reverse engineer that code, and learn by changing things around.

I found some code for a JS slideshow on CodePen and changed some things. Only now it will only show the first image and not cycle, and the buttons to move around fail as well.

I copied what I changed in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYV4R/1/)

The JS code looks like this (I included another snippet in the document in case that is a problem, the fiddle doesn't have it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*JQuery for fade in highlighting of links*/
$(".link").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color:'#fe57a1'}, 100);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#fff'}, 300);
});


/*Slide show code*/
var on = true;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(on) {slides()}on=true;},3000);

function slides(i) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[1].style.width="0px";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[2].style.width="100%";
    var slide = document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[0];
    document.getElementById("slide").appendChild(slide);
    if(i) {
        on = false; 
    }
}

function back_slide(i) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[1].style.width="0px";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[0].style.width="100%";
    var slide = document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[4];
    var slide2 = document.getElementsByClassName(".slideImage")[0];
    document.getElementById("slide").insertBefore(slide,slide2);
    if(i) {
        on = false; 
    }
}
});
```

The HTML and CSS is in the fiddle, I didn't know if I should include here in the post.

Comment: You need to check your console you have errors, when the slideshow trys to keep showing a different one

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("slideImage")` (remove the dot)

Comment: This is the first time I have had to do something where the console can help me a lot. I am not used to checking. I think I learned my lesson here haha. Removing the dot made a big difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure to check your console for errors when debugging. Usually its in the devtools (F12 on chrome and IE)

First you are trying to use a class selector with `getElementsByClassName`. This method just takes the class name not a selector. So `.slideImage` should be `slideImage` when passed to it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("slideImage")[1].style.width="0px";
```

Second your `slides` and `back_slide` functions (in the fiddle anyway) are declared within an onload event (the default option for jsfiddle) so it is not in global scope for the inline js to see

So change the jsfiddle setting or take the inline js out and use `addEventListener` to attach events to your buttons.

HTML

```
<button id="prevBtn" class="prev">&#171;</button>
<button id="nextBtn" class="next">&#187;</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("prevBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
   back_slide(true); 
});
document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click",function(){
   slides(true); 
});
```

The last problem you have is that you have

```
var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("slideImage")[4];
```

The array index should be 3, as array indexes start at 0.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gYV4R/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't done a lot up to this point which requires debugging in the console, so I hadn't even thought of it at first. I also get the getElementByClassName problem. I was working on JQuery earlier today and was used to selecting classes with (".class"), it didn't even click even though I was looking at all kinds of other code which showed me that problem.  Thanks again for your help, I made a couple of those changes and it is working a little better.

Comment: also if the `slide` variable in `back_slide` is supposed to represent the last slide, you can just get the last index of the array by using the `.length` property minus 1

Comment: yea I had been thinking about that. I have a background in Java, and if I were going to do something similar to this in Java, i would user a for loop to go through the array, and get the elements in the array with `.length`. Would this be something I should do here? Would that make the code more maintainable and flexible, or is that not how Javascript works?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is your element selection not working.
Change it to `document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[1]...`,you will see it running.

```
var on = true;
    var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
        if(on) {slides()}on=true;},3000);
    function slides(i) {
        document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[1].style.width="0px";
        document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[2].style.width="100%";
        var slide = document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
 document.getElementById("slide").appendChild(slide);
        if(i) {
           on = false; 
        }
    }
    function back_slide(i) {
        document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[1].style.width="0px";
        document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width="100%";
        var slide = document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[4];
        var slide2 = document.getElementById("slide").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
 document.getElementById("slide").insertBefore(slide,slide2);
        if(i) {
           on = false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: this was how the code was set up originally, but i changed it to a specific class because when selecting a div other divs within the page were being affected.